# How can I get the Video Bitrates on Android's Apps

Tags: android, video, streaming, logcat

I am trying to use logcat to get this additional info on the videos I am playing via different Apps, for example, Hulu, Netflix etc.

Is there a way I can see what Bit-rate is playing at all?

Thx!

Comment: There is no requirement that video players log bitrate data to LogCat or anywhere else.

Comment: If your device will support a network logging app you could record the URL requests and try to map them to the naming conventions used by Netflix etc for their different bit rate files (assuming they have one which includes this - they used to). You would be at the mercy of them changing their naming conventions however.